# Labels in stacked bar chart Tableau

Tags: bar-chart, tableau-api

I have a stacked bar chart with a total label 
[Bar Chart tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztk7A.png)

My problem is that when I select particular color(Part of bar chart), say Fuel from [Charge type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkuv7.png) I can not get the value of Fuel in that label. 
Is there a work around ? It is really crucial. Also, I am faily new, so can not post the question with images, please ignore the inconvenience.
Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly you should have a look at Tableau actions

Comment: If you press the Label button on the marks card, there are all sorts of advanced options to play with that determine which labels are displayed under which circumstances. Not sure if those will achieve your specific need, but try them out for starters.

Comment: @spijs, can you please be specific, which option are you talking about. Even a link with URL will help. I am fiddling around in vain and not being productive. Thanks.

Comment: @spijs I tried actions, it didn't help but thank you for trying

Comment: @radioactive from what I read in your question, a filter action should do what you want no? It filters everything you select. If you select the 'fuel' color, only fuel should remain. [Info](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_filter.html)

Comment: @spijs I accidentally chose Maximum in label, instead of Total and it gave me what I wanted. Problem solved. Thank you for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Label button in the Marks box, and choose the "Allow labels to overlap other marks" option. You can also choose the "Select" option under Marks to Label, if you only want to see the number when the color is selected-or "Highlighted" if you want to select from the legend.